# Incorrectly escaped sed command in Jenkinsfile

Tags: bash, groovy, sed, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run a sed command in a jenkinsfile which has a number of special characters in the search pattern and the replacement string is using two variables and a string.

The string I'm looking to replace in the file is:
`${data.terraform_remote_state.bucket.s3_bucket_name2}`

I need to replace all of it with a simple string, but grabbing the full string with brackets and all is proving difficult.

This is the latest thing I've tried, as well a few other attempts at either less escapes or trying to put the full string in into the sed command.

```
sh """
    S3_IAM_PATH1='\$\\{data\\.terraform_remote_state\\.bucket\\.s3_bucket_name1\\}'
    S3_IAM_PATH2='\$\\{data\\.terraform_remote_state\\.bucket\\.s3_bucket_name2\\}'
    sed -i s/\${S3_IAM_PATH1}/\${CLUSTER_NAME}-\${ID}-export/g $CLUSTER_TYPE/security/iam.tf
    sed -i s/\${S3_IAM_PATH2}/\${CLUSTER_NAME}-\${ID}-import/g $CLUSTER_TYPE/security/iam.tf
    cat $CLUSTER_TYPE/security/iam.tf
"""
```

The current output I'm getting is this:

```
+ S3_IAM_PATH1='$\{data\.terraform_remote_state\.bucket\.s3_bucket_name1\}'
+ S3_IAM_PATH2='$\{data\.terraform_remote_state\.bucket\.s3_bucket_name2\}'
+ sed -i 's/$\{data\.terraform_remote_state\.bucket\.s3_bucket_name1\}/thisCluster1-process211-export/g' DATA-CLUSTER/security/awsiam.tf
sed: -e expression #1, char 93: Invalid content of \{\}
```

Am willing to put out more code if needed but would really appreciate any help on this!

Comment: do you mean a literal `$`? if so, use `\$`. Not sure why you are doing `\{ ... \}`. They don't require escaping. Did you mean for capture groups? Then you want `\( ...\)`. When I pasted your cmd into my sed, it didn't complain. Good luck.

Comment: Definitely need to grab the literal $. As per the string in the start, that's the literal sequence I need to find. What's confused me with this so far is that testing in a terminal is giving me different results to running it through Jenkins. So I believe something is different in how it's being interpreted. Appreciate you taking the time to look though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got it running through the initial issue @yong supplied and a few minor tweaks in case anyone needs something similar in the future. The issue was the CLUSTER_TYPE variable not being set as Parameter in jenkinsfile but rather as something created in a previous stage. To access it, I needed to use double quotes. So some of the solution needed double quotes and the rest needed single:

```
sh '''
    S3_IAM_PATH1='${data.terraform_remote_state.bucket.s3_bucket_name1}'
    S3_IAM_PATH2='${data.terraform_remote_state.bucket.s3_bucket_name2}'
    sed -i "s/${S3_IAM_PATH1}/${CLUSTER_NAME}-${ID}-export/g" ''' + 
 "$CLUSTER_TYPE/security/iam.tf; " +
    '''sed -i "s/${S3_IAM_PATH2}/${CLUSTER_NAME}-${ID}-import/g" ''' 
 + """$CLUSTER_TYPE/security/iam.tf; 
    cat "$CLUSTER_TYPE/security/iam.tf" """
```

Like I said, not pretty but it works :) Thanks for the help guys!